# How do I exclude files from svelte-kit build?

Tags: sveltekit, vite

If I run `npm run build` with SvelteKit it seems to include all files from the `src` folder. Is it possible to exclude a certain file type (eg. `*test.js`)?

#### Example

1. Select demo app with  `npm init svelte@next my-app`
2. Add the following code to `src/routes/todos/foo.test.js`

   ```js
   describe('foo', () => {
     it('temp', () => {
       expect(true).toBe(false)
     })
   })
   ```
3. `npm run build`
4. `npm run preview`

Result: `describe is not defined`

#### Workaround

Move tests outside of `src`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** SvelteKit 1.0.0-beta now requires pages/endpoints to follow a specific naming pattern, so explicit file exclusion should no longer be needed.

SvelteKit specially handles files in the `routes/` directory with the following filenames (note the leading `+` in each filename):

- [`+page.svelte`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-svelte)
- [`+page.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-js)
- [`+page.server.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-server-js)
- [`+error.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#error)
- [`+layout.svelte`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout-svelte)
- [`+layout.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout-js)
- [`+layout.server.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout-server-js)
- [`+server.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server-js)

All [other files are ignored](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#other-files) and can be colocated in the `routes/` directory.

If, for some reason, you need to have a file that has a special name shown above, it's currently not possible to exclude that file from special processing.

---

<sup>Original outdated answer:</sup>

SvelteKit 1.0.0-beta supports a [`routes` configuration](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#configuration-routes) that enables file exclusion from the `src/routes` directory. The config value is a function that receives a file path as an argument, and returns `true` to use the file as a route.

For example, the following `routes` config excludes `*.test.js` files from routes:

```js
// sveltekit.config.js
⋮
const config = {
  kit: {
    ⋮
    routes: filepath => {
      return ![
        // exclude *test.js files
        /\.test\.js$/,

        // original default config
        /(?:(?:^_|\/_)|(?:^\.|\/\.)(?!well-known))/,
      ].some(regex => regex.test(filepath))
    },
  },
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltekit-exclude-files-v2?file=svelte.config.js)

Comment: `routes` option is not longer available under config. I can't figure out what's the current way of doing this. @tony19 please bless me with your knowledge

Comment: Thanks for coming back @tony19. My use case is more geared towards removing specific routes in build only. It goes like: I have an admin page for CRUD to my database. I use that during `npm run dev` I don't want to include that in the build. I had to do a major compromise of using adapter-static. Now I manually remove that page after build. Plus I had to give up on a lot of dynamicness just for this problem.

Comment: @Mooze I see. I wonder if there are simpler workarounds that don't require a special adapter. You could rename that file (e.g., from `routes/admin/dev/page.svelte` to `routes/admin/dev/+page.svelte`) in your `npm` script for `dev`.

Comment: That makes sense. It would do the job. I can keep it as `+page.svelte` and before build I can rename it to `page.svelte` inside the npm script like `mv +page.svelte page.svelte && vite build` @tony19 you're the man!